# PHP mktime different results based on minutes calculation

Tags: php

The following mktime produces a different result on the final echo.

```
php > echo mktime(7, 36, 0);
1406842560
php > echo mktime(7, 60 * 0.6, 0);
1406842560
php > echo mktime(7, 60 * ( 7.6 - 7.0 ), 0);
1406842500
```

This minute parameter is 36 for each mktime, and I've tried casting with (int) and intval, and also using the DateTime object's setTime function, but the exact same results.

This is just an example, I need the final mktime version to work as the previous two, as would be expected, because of the calculations done via variables in place of the numbers in example above.

Any ideas?

Comment: Interestingly, casting `60 * ( 7.6 - 7.0 )` to a string makes the function return 1406842560.

Comment: Although your answer works, semantically; having a (string) cast parameter passed to a function expecting an integer is confusing.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't have a PHP instance to hand but I assume that if you remove `mktime()` they all print out an exact 36?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a great explanation as to why this is the case - I have a feeling it's to do with the value you're passing being a float, rather than an integer, so there's probably a precision issue going on in the background.

The following appears to work correctly by adding the round() function around the second parameter:

```
echo mktime(7, round(60 * ( 7.6 - 7.0 )), 0);
```

Returns 1406842560.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, `ceil` works but `floor` doesn't!

Work:

```
mktime(7, ceil(60 * ( 7.6 - 7.0 )), 0); //1406810160
mktime(7, round(60 * ( 7.6 - 7.0 )), 0); //1406810160
mktime(7, (string)(60 * ( 7.6 - 7.0 )), 0); //1406810160
```

Don't:

```
mktime(7, floor(60 * ( 7.6 - 7.0 )), 0); //1406810100
mktime(7, intval(60 * ( 7.6 - 7.0 )), 0); //1406810100
mktime(7, (int)(60 * ( 7.6 - 7.0 )), 0); //1406810100
```

Comment: Very nice and complete answer!  I've awarded Melkior who came in earlier and has much less points.  Thank you.